# Closing Excel Application using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have used the following without success. The active workbook closes, indeed, but the excel window remains open.

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Which is the command that terminates the application?

EDIT

To say a little more: In the workbook Open event I run a macro. I want to terminate the application when that macro finishes. I also tried this without success.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Macro_MyJob
   Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Where should I put this Application.Quit command?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think your problem is that it's closing the document that calls the macro before sending the command to quit the application.

Your solution in that case is to not send a command to close the workbook. Instead, you could set the "Saved" state of the workbook to true, which would circumvent any messages about closing an unsaved book. Note: this does not save the workbook; it just makes it look like it's saved.

```
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
```

and then, right after

```
Application.Quit
```

Answer (score 15):

To avoid the Save prompt message, you have to insert those lines

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

After saving your work, you need to use this line to quit the Excel application

```
Application.Quit
```

Don't just simply put those line in Private Sub Workbook_Open() unless you got do a correct condition checking, else you may spoil your excel file.

For safety purpose, please create a module to run it. The following are the codes that i put:

```
Sub testSave()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Hope it help you solve the problem.

Comment: This works but is only useful if you do want to save the workbook. Not sure if the questioner intended to do so.

Answer (score 8):

```
Sub TestSave()
Application.Quit
ThisWorkBook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub
```

This seems to work for me, Even though looks like am quitting app before saving, but it saves...

Comment: This worked for me too. However, you are missing a colon before the equal sign, like this: SaveChanges:=False

Comment: are you sure it saves? because savechanges := false

Answer (score 6):

```
Application.Quit
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a certain sequence that seems to work as you can see below:

```
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to close just one excel window and not the entire application, so, I needed to tell which exact window to close, without saving it.

The following lines work just fine:

```
Sub test_t()
  Windows("yourfilename.xlsx").Activate
  ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Sub button2_click()
'
' Button2_Click Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 2").Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Logout"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 2").Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Button2_Click"
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```