# Excel does not completely close when using Workbook.Close

Tags: vba, excel

In the macro I'm running, I end with closing the last Excel Workbook that's open. When I run it everything closes except one window which doesn't have a spread sheet, just a light-blue backdrop. Am I using a wrong command or is there just no way to close all open windows?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628252/closing-excel-application-using-vba) is a post asking my exact question, but the solution isn't working for me.

Here are the last two commands that I'm using:

```
'
' Closes Populated JD Form
'
    Workbooks(name).Close SaveChanges:=False

'
' Closes Transfer Template
'
    Workbooks("Transfer Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try putting `Application.Quit` after the Close statement.

Comment: @DeanOC Under the last line, correct? If so, it didn't work.

Comment: It worked for me @bdkong - running `Application.Quit` gave me a popup "Do you want to save?". This can be disabled by adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, but i don't think you will need it in your case.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean `Application.quit` doesn't work? Does it give an error? Does it close the workbook, but not the application? What happens if you run this command in the Immediate window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't turn the display alerts off as it will suppress any genuine questions.

Use this instead

```
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```

This will stop Excel for asking about saving changes as it now thinks that it has been saved already. A good example of this is your personal macro workbook, I use mine a LOT and am always creating or modifying code in there. If I turn the alert off and there are changes in my personal workbook, I lose them all.

Try not to bulk fix possible scenarios where possible. Another example is errors, have an error trapping routine and deal with it as needed as opposed to a blanket statement of on error resume next.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to fix my trouble with @DeanOC 's answer. First of all I don't want to save changes. Secondly, it doesn't give   me the option to save because I've already denoted that I don't want to save it.

Comment: It doesn't save it it just fools excel into thinking it has been saved so it closes without prompting you

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. It's still not working though :/

Comment: Found my problem. I had a bit of code that was slightly above the app quit code that was closing the workbook. Deleted that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the question doesn't remain unanswered, using both suggestions

(credit to @DeanOC and @user1274820)

---

```
'Closes Populated JD Form
Workbooks(Name).Close SaveChanges:=False

'Closes Transfer Template
Workbooks("Transfer Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Quit
End With
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Once I removed **atpvbaen.xls** from my references, application.quit worked as advertised.

I was tearing my hair out - until I realized I had atpvbaen.xls set as a reference - which was ANOTHER excel thread left alive.  I didn't need it for this application, so I disabled it.  In the VB Editor, `Tools => References un-check atpvbaen.xls.` If I had needed it, maybe shutting that one down deliberately would have worked.