# Close workbook with Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a User form in Excel, so when i open the xlsm-file it only opens the user form, and the workbook is hidden.

But when i close the user form with the [X]-button I want it to close both the workbook and the user form without saving.

When I close the user form now, and try to open the same file again, it says that it is already/stil open.

Start up code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.Visible = False
 Fordelinger.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Close code:

```
Private Sub Fordelinger_Deactivate()
Application.Quit
Workbooks("EstimatDOK.xlsm").Close True
End Sub
```

Can anyone help? :)

Comment: Does your code reach the line after `Application.Quit`?

Comment: I tried to set the Application.Quit line last, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried this solution yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628252/closing-excel-application-using-vba

Comment: if you open your task manager and see that excel is still open, you may have to set excel=0, search for "Why won't excel close"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below code to restrict close (X) button

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "The X is disabled, please use a button on the form to Exit.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

may be you wanted this code in the UserForm code pane

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you get what you needed?