# Excel freeze after close workbook in Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to close the workbooks after finish executing macro. 
So i use this code

```
 Workbooks("RPA 1.xlsm").Close
```

However, after the RPA 1.xlsm closed, the other active workbook is freezed and can't be closed. It seems like something got stucked.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer for your question.

[Closing Excel Application using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628252/closing-excel-application-using-vba)

Maybe the workbook still not saved that's why it freezes. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post a comment because I need 50 reputation. I said also that the workbook still not saved so maybe it's the problem. @EmanuelPirovano

Comment: I tried using application.quit. However, all the excel file opened are closed. I only want to close the specific excel file

Comment: Usually when i first open another workbook then i'll go ahead and name it. 
    `Set AnotherWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook`

then when i'm done with it i just close it with
`AnotherWorkbook.Close`

Answer (score 0):

Take this example  :

```
Const xlAscending = 1
Const xlYes = 1
Dim filePath
    filePath = "C:\Users\book1.xlsx"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim objWorkbook
Set objWorkbook = _ 
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objExcel.Range("A1")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
'objExcel.Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlWorkbookNormal'
objWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

please conctrate on following :

```
 objWorkbook.Save
    objExcel.Application.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing 
 objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Visible = false means that excel will not open

DisplayAlerts = false allow you to ignore msgBox that pop up when you try to change excel .

the first 2 commands are to close excel file.

hope all clear , let me know if you have more questions