# Locating cells in an external workbook and copying over information automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am trying to create an automatic filing system. I want to copy invoice information directly over from an invoice 'InvoiceMaker' workbook to a separate 'InvoiceTracker' workbook each time an invoice has been filled out. I have a long line of free invoice numbers in the 'Tracker' workbook and i want to assign specific information from each new invoice to each free invoice number. I have been writing to code to automatically search for the invoice number using 'find' in the column B where these free invoice numbers are located. Once this has been found the information in specific cells can be copied over directly to this row of cells.

I have come across a problem with finding the location of the invoice numbers in the external workbook. The error message 91 keeps recurring 'Object Variable or With block variable not set', even though a name has been given an object and set correctly. The find result comes up with 'nothing' even though there is a value in that cell in this external workbook. I changed the format of the cell and it still does not work!

```
Sub test()
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Dim Destination As Workbook
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RowNumber As Long
    Dim InvoiceNumber As String
    'Names the workbooks
    Set Source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\InvoiceMaker.xlsm")
    Set Destination = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\InvoiceTrack.xlsx")
    'Picks the invoice number
    InvoiceNumber = Source.Sheets(1).Range("H9")
    'Finds the row of the sheet
```

The problem stems from below with 'error 91' and I cannot seem to problem solve it! I cannot seem to achieve anything but 'nothing' upon running. All of the sheet locations are correct, I have tried everything!

```
    Set Rng = Destination.Sheets(1).Columns("B:B").Find(What:=InvoiceNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    RowNumber = Rng.Row` 


     `'Copies the data from the source
    Source.Sheets(1).Range("C8").Copy
    'Pastes to the destination
    Destination.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNumber, 3).PasteSpecial
    Source.Sheets(1).Range("H11").Copy
    Destination.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNumber, 4).PasteSpecial
    Source.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Copy
    Destination.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNumber, 5).PasteSpecial
    Source.Sheets(1).Range("H10").Copy
    Destination.Sheets(1).Cells(RowNumber, 6).PasteSpecial
    Source.Save
    'Destination.Save
    'Destination.Close
End Sub
```

If someone is kind enough to look over this for me, can you please look at the special paste section and correct me if i am coding incorrectly!

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code line by line so you can get a better idea of what's going on and localize the issue.  Also see this overview of [Debugging VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189158/debugging-vba-locating-problems-and-troubleshooting-methods) from Chip Pearson. You should also see the [tour] (which earns a badge!) as well as the [help/ontopic] and also "[ask]"  and plus "[mcve]".

Comment: It is probably because if `Find` doesn't find anything then `Rng` is `Nothing` and that doesn't have a `.Row`. So probably check directly after `Find()` if `If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing found so exit`

Comment: have you tried adding yourcode.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues ? Also I'd try replacing cells(RowNumber,3) by Range("C"&RowNumber)

Comment: I have tried debugging it and have added in different numbers for the `Find()`  number and still returns 'nothing' under the locals window. Is there another way of locating cells containing specific numbers in another workbook? The `Exit Sub` doesnt seem to solve the overarching problem or am i wrong?

Comment: @GeorgeWest Are you sure that you are acting on the correct sheet? `Sheets(1)` means the first sheet in the bottom tab bar, no matter what it is named. Be aware that `Sheet1`, `Sheets("Sheet1")` and `Sheets(1)` can be 3 totally different sheets.