# Trouble with proper indexing new lines

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping through columns and storing them in values s and s1. I need to add count order for as many lines as it's needed for which I'm trying to use j index. Getting picture like this all the time:

[image: Current result]

And the desired result should be as follows:

[image]

```
s = ""
s1 = ""
j = 1
Do            
s = j & ". " & s & Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Offset(1, 0).Value & vbCrLf
s1 = j & ". " & s1 & Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Offset(1, 0).Value & vbCrLf
i = i + 1
j = j + 1            
Loop While Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be incremented like this:

```
s = s & j & ". " & Cells(i, 2).Offset(1, 0) & vbCrLf
```

Thus, the `s` value is incrementing over itself.

In general, whenever such problems appear and it is tough to understand why a string is being formatted, try to debug step-by-step. E.g., write `Stop` on the code and print the string, which is avialable up to now. Like this:

```
Do
    s = s & j & ". " & Cells(i, 2).Offset(1, 0) & vbCrLf
    s1 = j & ". " & s1 & Cells(i, 3).Offset(1, 0) & vbCrLf
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
    Debug.Print s
    Stop
Loop While Cells(i, 3) <> ""
```

Then the magic becomes easier to understand. Pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> and checking the current values with hovering over them in VBE is another option for step-by-step debugging.

[Debugging VBA, Locating Problems, and Troubleshooting Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189158/debugging-vba-locating-problems-and-troubleshooting-methods)

Comment: Thank you, it works! You wouldn't believe, F8 was the first thing I tried to do, I also dragged s and s1 values by alt clicking to watchlist  and checked their values at immediate window, still dont understand how I would come up with the right solution, guess it's more of 'practice' thing.
One last question: do you know why it's adding last index as empty? https://imgur.com/j2Zko69

Comment: @MDoskarin - it is reading from here - `Cells(i, 2).Offset(1, 0)` and the condition is `Cells(i, 3) <> ""`. If you change the condition of the loop like this - `Do While Cells(i, 2).Offset(1, 0) <> ""`, it would be ok.

Comment: Gosh, simplicity is genius. Thank you!