Cant seem to get my variables to add together , just get NaN EXCELScript
So I am a programming scrub, but I'm decent in general at trying to understand examples of what other people have done.  However I am hitting a road block on this one excel script file I am trying to write.
Basics of what I am trying to accomplish is read 2 cells, add them together, and write to a 3rd cell (eventually I will overwrite one of the original cells) so I can make and adjustment "form" for a dataset.
Here is what I have:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    //Get Value from Modification
    let val = workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("F2").getValue();
    //Get Value from original
    let val2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Parts Master List").getRange(val).getValue();
    //Add values together and overwrite original
    workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("D4").setValue(Number(val) + (val2));
}

Should be simple, doesnt really error out, but when it writes the data into D4, it cmes out as NaN.  I suspect I am not storing the variables properly?
Thanks,
Greg
I have tried numerous things.  Removing the variables, and just add in numbers which proved script writes properly, and adds properly.  I tried adjusting let val: number = instead of its current state (no help)  I have tried screaming into the void?
Updated Code:
Based on recommendations from Vexen Crabtree I have updated my script some (still don't have error checking)
   function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    //Get Value from Cell Ref
    let DynamicCell = workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("F2").getValue();
    //Get Value from Modification
    let ModificationCell = workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("D2").getValue();
    //Get Value from original Master
    let MasterCell = workbook.getWorksheet("Parts Master List").getRange(DynamicCell).getValue();
    //Add values together and overwrite original
    workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("D4").setValue(String(MasterCell)+String(ModificationCell));
}

I think my issue is in:
let MasterCell = workbook.getWorksheet("Parts Master List").getRange(DynamicCell).getValue();

as it is not returning a number when I sent the output straight to the cell. Going to keep doing some testing.

in debug window, Add a watch for val and val2 and step into the script    then watch as the values get set when you press F8 to go to the next line.  You'll see what vlaue is being assigned.  Or pull up the immediate window (ctrl-G) and use debug.print(val) debug.print(val2) to evaluate what is being assigned.  once you see the vlaues, you'll likely understand the problem. See-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189158/debugging-vba-locating-problems-troubleshooting-methods

NaN = Not a Number so it's trying to do math on something that's not numeric and since you didn't declare and define a type for val or val2, they can be any data type which is being set at Run Time.  By using strong types, you can encounter errors before you run intot his

Good Advice xQbert.  It have narrowed it down to my Dynamic Cell not returning information at the moment...  Not gonna lie, troubleshooting code makes my eyes cross a bit.

good luck. coding isn't for everyone; but those suggestions/links should help you here and with future endeavors as far as troubleshooting the issue.

I don't think your logic adds up.
val is being set to a value from a cell, and then, val2 is being set according to a range from val. So, the 'val' must be a string like "A2" or "A9".
But then, you are adding 'val' (a string) to val2 (which I presume you expect to be a number). It'll never work, and, it won't produce a numerical output.
To see what your two values are, try changing this:
workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("D4").setValue(Number(val) + (val2));

Into something like:
workbook.getWorksheet("Input Test (WIP)").getRange("D4").setValue(String(val) + String(val2)); #convert all to strings, and see what it looks like

This will display them both as strings (the most likely format to be able to 'add' them together, then you can look to see what value is actually coming out.
You should also add some code to deal with the possibility that val comes out blank, or that it refers to a cell that doesn't have information (and therefore, can't be added).
I think should also add a tag to your post saying what language you're using ('Excelscript'), because it's not the classic VBA that most would assume.

Thanks, this actually helped a lot (hasn't fixed my issue yet, but did make me realize a huge mistake.)
The val2 is not pulling the information from the cell I want.  I put the output for Val and Val2, and val2 is blank.  So 1, error checking would be a great addition, s, not sure why val2 isn't pulling anything.... yet
This is an excel script, but I didn't see that as an option for the tags.  I am using excel scripts instead of VBA because its running on a web based shared sheet, and that's the only way I know to program for those.

I was going to mention before, but, 'val' is very frequently a keyword or a named function, and I would avoid using it as a variable name in general.

You Are ALSO right that my logic was messed up.  val is a cell on the sheet that is running an address formula, so its not even the cell I should be calculating with, it is being used to try and dynamically change val2.
