# Excel Application does not close-logical error

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to close the workbook using Excel VBA  but I want to disable DisplayAlerts.

I am using the following code:

```
Sub Close_Worksheettwo()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

However, VBA closes only the ActiveWorkbook and the Application(Excel) remains open. There are no syntax errors.

What's happening?

Comment: What happens when you put `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after `ActiveWorkbook.Close`?

Comment: This might help [Closing Excel Application using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628252/closing-excel-application-using-vba)

Comment: @АлексейP. Thanks. This makes sense now!

Comment: @SiddharthRout. Nothing happens. I used the question thread above! and tried a few sequences that worked.